# Multiple tasks showing up in my JFrame application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, task

I am creating a Java Swing based desktop application in Netbeans. The application consists of some JFrames to get and display user data. The problem I am facing is that when a parent frame loads another frame, 2 separate tasks are visible in the Windows Task Manager. When the child frame loads its child frame, one more task appears in the Task Manager. Do you have a clue as to what I may be doing wrong out here?

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JDialog instead of second JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice to just use one JFrame for the main control of the application. Using JDialogs for the rest of your windows will give you full modality control over them and no multiple tasks visible in your task manager.